# Flexicious : single footer with dynamic levels

Tags: apache-flex, flexicious

Using ultimate flexicious datagrid with enableDynamicLevels="true", I try to have an unique footer instead of one per level.

Is that possible ? And if yes, how ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version are you on? If you get the latest version, there should be an event dynamicLevelCreated. The level property of the event dispatched is the newly created level. You can set enableFooters=false in there. `dynamicLevelCreated="testODG1_dynamicLevelCreatedHandler(event)"`

```
protected function testODG1_dynamicLevelCreatedHandler(event:FlexDataGridEvent):void
            {
                event.level.enableFooters=false;
            }
```